# How to schedule sqoop job using crontab

Tags: hadoop, cron, sqoop

I have created sqoop job which is working perfectly but when I am trying to schedule it using crontab it is not working.I have scheduled it as follows,

`50 12 * * * sqoop job --exec myjob_direct_append >> /home/training/my_Local/direct_append1.log`

Please Guide the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. Where are you executing this from? Is it a system crontab (usually */etc/crontab*) ?

Try scheduling:

```
* * * * * sqoop job --exec myjob_direct_append >> /home/training/my_Local/direct_append1.log 2>&1
```

This would run every minute and log any error message to the *direct_append1.log* so you can debug the issue quickly.

Comment: Hello Prakul,thank you for your reply.I am executing it from normal terminal as by opening editor as,                                                                                 [training@localhost ~]$ crontab -e
and pasting,* * * * * sqoop job --exec myjob_direct_append >> /home/training/my_Local/direct_append1.log 2>&1 in editor and saving it by :wq  but      still it is not working please guide what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: hello @user8167344 where you able to resolve this issue

Comment: Hi Vaishak,no it did not solve,it was long time back and currently I am not working on sqoop so did not pursue answer for it.Thank you!